# How could I hide the comments from documentation

Tags: swift, xcode, hidden

I have a problem I can't seem to solve. I wish I could hide the comments documentation of properties, methods... but when I use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> (available in “Editor” » “Code Folding” » “Fold Comment Block”) Xcode hides only the classical comments but not the comment documentation. If anyone has a suggestion it would be very cool, thanks ^^.

Comment: ctrl+cmd+shift+< is collapsing multiline comments for `/* .. */`, `//`, `/** .. */`, and `///` down to a single line for me. E.g., https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmKYk.png

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your answer, I thought it didn’t work but it was normal because my comment were only one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Go to Editor -> Code Folding -> Fold Comment Blocks

or shortcut:

Fold: Shift + Control + Command + Left

Unfold: Shift + Control + Command + Right

[image]